# Speeding up UrlFetch Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The goal is to run through about 10,000 lines of links. Determine which have page numbers > 3 and highlight the first column. I have all of this done, but the problem is that it takes Url Fetch too long, I run into a maximum run time error. Is there anyway I can speed up this code so I can run through the 10,000 lines?

```
 function readColumns() {
  //program is going to run through column 3 by going through the amount of rows, truncating last three characters to see if pdf, then highlighting first column
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var columns = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rowNum = columns.getNumRows();
  var values = columns.getValues();
  var html;
  var htmlString;

  for(var i = 1; i <= rowNum; i++){
    var columnLogger = values[i][2];
    try{
        html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(values[i][2], 
      {
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
      }
      );
    }catch(e){
      Logger.log("Error at line " + i);
      var error = true;
    }
    htmlString = html.getContentText();
    var index = htmlString.indexOf("Pages") + 6;
    var pageNumber = parseInt(htmlString.charAt(index),10);

    var lastChars = "" + columnLogger.charAt(columnLogger.length-3) + columnLogger.charAt(columnLogger.length-2) + columnLogger.charAt(columnLogger.length-1);

    if((error) || (!lastChars.equals("pdf") && values[i][6].equals("") && !pageNumber >= 3)){

       //goes back to first column and highlights yellow
       var cellRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowNum, 3)
       var cell = cellRange.getCell(i+1, 1)
       cell.setBackground("yellow");
    }


  }


}
```

Edit - short scripts:

```
function foreverCall(){
  var start = 1480;

  for(;;){
    readColumns(start);
    start = start + 100;
  }

}


function readColumns(start) {
  //program is going to run through column 3 by going through the amount of rows, truncating last three characters to see if pdf, then highlighting first column
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var columns = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rowNum = columns.getNumRows();
  var values = columns.getValues();
  var html;
  var htmlString;
  var error;

  for(var i = start; i < start+100; i++){
   if(loop(values, error, html, htmlString, rowNum, sheet, columns, i)){

        var cellRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rowNum, 3)
        var cell = cellRange.getCell(i, 1)
        cell.setBackground("yellow"); 

   }
  }


}

function loop(values, error, html, htmlString, rowNum, sheet, columns, i){
   var columnLogger = values[i][2];


   var lastChars = columnLogger.slice(-4);

    if(!lastChars.equals(".pdf") && values[i][6].equals("")){


      return true;


    }else{

      try{
        error = false
        html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(values[i][2].toString());
        if(html == null){
          error = true;
        }
       }catch(e){
         Logger.log("Error at line " + i);
         error = true;
       }
      if(!error){
       htmlString = html.getContentText();
       var index = htmlString.indexOf("Pages") + 6;
       var pageNumber = parseInt(htmlString.charAt(index),10);

      }
      //goes back to first column and highlights yellow
       if(error || !pageNumber >= 3){
        return true;
       }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can replace this:**

```
var lastChars = "" + columnLogger.charAt(columnLogger.length-3) + columnLogger.charAt(columnLogger.length-2) + columnLogger.charAt(columnLogger.length-1);
```

**With this:**

```
var lastChars = columnLogger.slice(-3);
```

You could also initiate the fetch script from an html sidebar or dialog to run short batches and then return back to the success handler which could then initiate another batch depending upon the return value.  The return value could also be used to start the next batch at the next row. It would actually take longer to run but you could probably stay well under the script limit by keeping your batches small.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I really only need the first 50 chars of this URL fetch app, but it has to load the whole page everytime. Is there anyway, in order to speed up the execution time, to make it only load a short amount of the html? Perhaps some sort of timeout (ie. 20 ms) that would make it skip this command? This would truncate the html hopefully.

Comment: I don't really know but I'm wondering if you perhaps could disable javascript and or cookies for the fetch.  You may get a significantly different page but you may be able to get the text that you need. Really that's a total guess on my part.

Comment: Ok that's alright. Is this kind of what you were suggesting for keeping it under the script limit? I edited the question

Comment: No.  I was suggesting that you could trigger batches of fetches from a sidebar and when that number of fetches was complete it would end the script with a return to a success handler thus ending the script timing and the success handler could pass a token back to the script starting it again at the next row.  It would take longer but each batch could be keep well under the max script limit.  If you're with google.script.run I'm talking about using those handlers to issue another batch.

Comment: See that's where I'm a little lost. I don't know what you mean by triggering a fetch from a "sidebar" and I'm not sure how to return to a success handler such that it ends the scripts timing.

Comment: Another thing, and sorry for all the questions. Is it possible to multithread? What if I created 40 different threads that all did 200 lines? Then it would finish in 6 minutes

Comment: I added a small block diagram to my answer that summarizes the process.

Comment: Yeh.  I don't know how to do that.  It's certainly possible for their servers but I would think you'd have to be a pretty high priority process to get 200 threads.  I think that would boil down to how much cash do you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with the line with

var lastChars = columnLogger.slice(-3);

Comment: Would you mind formatting the code with four spaces before it so that it is a little more readable in the browser, and perhaps explain why this works?